# StreamSocketListener and "An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal." error

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx

I have a simplest WinRt c++/cx template project in Visual Studio in which i modified only three lines in MainPage constructor and added simple event handler like this:

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    auto listener = ref new Windows::Networking::Sockets::StreamSocketListener;
    listener->ConnectionReceived += ref new Windows::Foundation::TypedEventHandler<Windows::Networking::Sockets::StreamSocketListener ^, Windows::Networking::Sockets::StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs ^>(this, &App3::MainPage::OnConnectionReceived);
    Concurrency::create_task(listener->BindEndpointAsync(ref new Windows::Networking::HostName("127.0.0.1"), "6667")).get();
}


void MainPage::OnConnectionReceived(Windows::Networking::Sockets::StreamSocketListener ^sender, Windows::Networking::Sockets::StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs ^args)
{
    throw ref new Platform::NotImplementedException();
}
```

After running this project i'm getting debugger error like this:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0F983C68 (msvcr120d_app.dll) in XXX.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.
```

This project has enabled "Internet (Client and Server)" and "Private Networks" capabilities.
So my question is: why i'm getting this error? It's a WinRt bug?

Comment: Don't call `.get()` on the UI thread. Also note that local loopback doesn't work for UWP by default (search other SO questions for work-around).

Comment: Why can't i call `get()` on the UI thread? I know it is bad practice to freeze UI thread but what does this error mean?

Comment: Because the C++ PPL runtime will throw if you do this. But you might be hitting a different problem even sooner, since you don't indicate exactly where the error originated from.

Comment: An unhandled exception comes with a call stack, so that you know, where the error was raised. Please include this call stack in your question. Now you should narrow in on the error. Since you only added 3 lines of code, simply remove them one at a time, until the error goes away. That should take you closer to the core issue.